# Count number of elements to get from lookup query for nested referenced array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have the following categories collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e1d8c3ed06661d2b06a7c46"),
    "status" : "active",
    "noOfLevels" : 3,
    "levels" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e1db2237a265cfe50dfdb18"), 
        ObjectId("5e1db22b7a265cfe50dfdb19"), 
        ObjectId("5e1db23b7a265cfe50dfdb1a")
    ],
    "name" : "Fuel",
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d8c3ed06661d2b06a7c46"),
    "status" : "active",
    "noOfLevels" : 3,
    "levels" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e1db2237a265cfe50dfdb18"), 
        ObjectId("5e1db22b7a265cfe50dfdb19"), 
        ObjectId("5e1db23b7a265cfe50dfdb1a")
    ],
    "name" : "Feeds",
}
```

In the above collection levels _id has been stored as a reference to populate later.

Level collection has this items:-

```
{
 levelName: { type: String, required: true },
  levelDesc: { type: String },
  levelNo: { type: Number, required: true },
  categoryId: { type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'trainingCategories', required: true },
  videoId: [{ type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'trainingVideoMaster' }],
},
{
 levelName: { type: String, required: true },
  levelDesc: { type: String },
  levelNo: { type: Number, required: true },
  categoryId: { type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'trainingCategories', required: true },
  videoId: [{ type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'trainingVideoMaster' }],
}
```

I am using aggregation and lookup to find items in categories collection, in my final result I need counts for videoIds which is present on each level of the particular categories.

Need final result like this:-

```
 {
                        name: 'How to save fuel',
                        catNo: 1,
                        noOfLevels: 3,
                        totalVideos: 4
    },
    {
                        name: 'Feeds',
                        catNo: 2,
                        noOfLevels: 3,
                        totalVideos: 3
     }
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: @Ashh something like this 
Cat.aggregate([
     { $match: {status: 'active' }},
     { $lookup: {from: 'traininglevels', localField: 'levels', foreignField: '_id', as: 'trainingLevels'} },
   
     { "$project": {
        noOfLevels: 1,
        name: 1,
        catNo: 1,
        createdAt: 1,
        trainingLevels: {$sum:'$trainingLevels.videoId'}
       }}
      ])
But I know it doesn't compliance with the aggregation scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `trainingLevels` array to make it an object property and then you can use `.dot` notation to get the `videoId` length.

```
Cat.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": "active" } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "traininglevels",
    "let": { "levels": "$levels" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$levels"] }}},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "totalVideos": { "$sum": { "$size": "$videoId" }}
      }}
    ]
    "as": "trainingLevels"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$trainingLevels" },
  { "$project": {
    "noOfLevels": 1,
    "name": 1,
    "catNo": 1,
    "createdAt": 1,
    "trainingLevels": "$trainingLevels.totalVideos"
  }}
])
```

Comment: I get repeated categories in this case:-
"categories": [
            {
                "_id": "5e1d8c3ed06661d2b06a7c46",
                "noOfLevels": 3,
                "name": "HOW TO SAVE FUEL",
                "catNo": 1,
                "totalVideos": 0            },
            {
                "_id": "5e1d8c3ed06661d2b06a7c46",
                "noOfLevels": 3,
                "name": "HOW TO SAVE FUEL",
                "catNo": 1,
                "totalVideos": 5,
            },

Comment: Is it possible to have same `_id` for the multiple documents? I can see `"foreignField": "_id"` which definitely means you are matching with `_id` of the `traininglevels` collection and that should not be the same for the multiple documents.

Comment: In category collection levels are referenced as an array of ObjectId,
also, levels has videoIds as an array of ObjectId.
What happened here is that it returns data for objects which has videoId present in levels collection. 
And it didn't returns the data for levels where videoId is empty array[].

Comment: And grouping is also not achieved with this.

Comment: Your answer has worked for the data in categories collection which does not have the levels as empty array, categories which has levels empty [] does not return from the query.
Adding this solve the problem:-
`{ $unwind: { path: "$trainingLevels", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ "$project": { "noOfLevels": 1,  "name": 1, "catNo": 1,  "createdAt": 1,
"totalVideos":  { "$cond":{  if: {  $gte: ['$trainingLevels.totalVideos', 0]  },
then: "$trainingLevels.totalVideos",
else: 0
  }} }}
])`